# Не работает ::after и ::before

Tags: css

```html
<body>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body, html {
    background-color: #ECEFF4;
    height: 100%;
}
.tc {
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.form-reg {
    width: 390px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 77px 55px 33px 55px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.form-action {
    width: 100%;
}
.form-name {
    display: block;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
}
.form-title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}
input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
.form-input {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
    margin-bottom: 37px;
}
.input-email, .input-login, .input-password {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #555555;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.focus {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.focus::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    background: #6a7dfe;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
}
.focus::after {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #999999;
    line-height: 1.2;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
button, input {
    overflow: visible;
}
</style>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="form-reg">
                <form action="" class="form-action">
                    <span class="form-name">Регистрация</span>
                    <span class="form-title"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/100/000000/bomb-with-burning-wick.png" alt=""></span>
                    
                    <div class="form-input" data-validate="Введите E-Mail">
                        <input class="input-email" type="text" name="email">
                        <span class="focus" data-placeholder="EMail"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-input" data-validate="Введите логин">
                        <input class="input-login" type="text" name="login">
                        <span class="focus" data-placeholder="Login"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-input" data-validate="Введите пароль">
                        <input class="input-password" type="password" name="password">
                        <span class="focus" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

В чем проблема ? По идее все верно сделано.
При нажатии на поле, подсказка (Email, Login, Password) должны подниматься вверх и полоска заливаться градиентом. Пример: [prntscr.com/nwgkrn](http://prntscr.com/nwgkrn)

Comment: Что, как и почему здесь должно работать?

Comment: При нажатии на поле, подсказка (Email, Login, Password) должны подниматься вверх и полоска заливаться градиентом.
Пример: http://prntscr.com/nwgkrn

Comment: Никаких `:focus`, `:active` или `:hover` в стилях я не обнаружил. Следовательно, почему что-то должно меняться при нажатии, непонятно

Comment: https://colorlib.com/etc/lf/Login_v2/index.html
Следовательно из этого примера, там нет ни :focus, ни :active, есть только :after и :before, тем самым все работает прекрасно, перекопипастил в точности - но у меня не работает.

Comment: В вашем примере скорее всего замешан JavaScript ) Событие само по себе ниоткуда не может появиться. А `before` и `after` - всего лишь псевдоэлементы... почти как div, только не сами по себе - а зависимы от родителя) P.s. они кстати в любом случае не могут работать без `content`. Даже если он пустой, нужно указать `content: "";`

Comment: Как можно обойтись в моем случаи JS, и сделать на CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Селектор `:focus` (не путать с классом `.focus`) поддерживают только элементы `<input>, <textarea>, <button>` (возможно кого-то не знаю). 

• Запись двух селекторов через пробел, означает что второй находится где-то внутри первого. В данном случае input, на котором сейчас поставлен фокус - должен находться где-то внутри .form-input.

• Символ `~` находит элемент, который находится где-то ниже в коде от первого. При этом они оба не должны быть обернуты в дополнительные теги. В данном случае нужный `span.focus` прямо под `input:focus`, поэтому сработает.

`.form-input input:focus ~ .focus::after {...}` — Перевод на Русский: Поменять что-то у псевдоэлемента `:after` у класса `.focus`, но который находится ниже в коде от `input`, на который поставлен фокус, и который находится внутри `.form-input`

```
.form-input input:focus ~ .focus::after {
  transition: 0.5s;
  top: -10px;
}

.form-input input:focus ~ .focus::before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Почти есть желаемый результат, но если ввести что-нибудь в инпут и убрать фокус - оно возвращается на место. Посмотрел на исходный код - а на инпут добавляется класс `has-val`, когда в нем что-то введено. Дальше уже без JS никак.

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('.form-input input');
//Нашли и сохранили все инпуты внутри блоков с этим классом
var i;
for( i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
  //Для каждого из них добавляем функцию, которая будет запускаться при вводе текста
  input[i].addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(this.value == ""){
      //Если текст внутри окажется равным пустой строке - убираем класс
      this.classList.remove('has-val');
    } else { // Иначе - добавляем.
      this.classList.add('has-val'); 
    }
  });
}
```

И к добавляемому классу, тоже небольшой CSS:

```
.form-input input.has-val ~ .focus::after {
  transition: 0.5s;
  top: -10px;
}

.form-input input.has-val ~ .focus::before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Результат:

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('.form-input input');
var i;
for( i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
  input[i].addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(this.value == ""){ 
      this.classList.remove('has-val');
    } else { 
      this.classList.add('has-val'); 
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body, html {
    background-color: #ECEFF4;
    height: 100%;
}
.tc {
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.form-reg {
    width: 390px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 77px 55px 33px 55px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.form-action {
    width: 100%;
}
.form-name {
    display: block;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
}
.form-title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}
input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
.form-input {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
    margin-bottom: 37px;
}
.input-email, .input-login, .input-password {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #555555;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.focus {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.focus::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    background: #6a7dfe;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
}
.focus::after {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #999999;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
button, input {
    overflow: visible;
}


.form-input input:focus ~ .focus::after {
  transition: 0.5s;
  top: -12px;
}

.form-input input:focus ~ .focus::before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-input input.has-val ~ .focus::after {
  transition: 0.5s;
  top: -12px;
}

.form-input input.has-val ~ .focus::before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="form-reg">
      <form action="" class="form-action">
        <span class="form-name">Регистрация</span>
        <span class="form-title"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/100/000000/bomb-with-burning-wick.png" alt=""></span>
        
        <div class="form-input" data-validate="Введите E-Mail">
          <input class="input-email" type="text" name="email">
          <span class="focus" data-placeholder="EMail"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input" data-validate="Введите логин">
          <input class="input-login" type="text" name="login">
          <span class="focus" data-placeholder="Login"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input" data-validate="Введите пароль">
          <input class="input-password" type="password" name="password">
          <span class="focus" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вот еще бы знать что в has-val, дальше уже разберусь сам.

Comment: Дописал вариант с JS) А вы с ним хоть немного знакомы?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, не подумал в JS полезть, как глянул - сразу стало все на свои места.

http://prntscr.com/nwh3t1 - результат))